# How to figure out use a modal segue instead of push segue

Tags: ios6, segue

I have this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFotosAloj"]) {
        localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:localGallery animated:YES];
}
```

I want to use modal segues, so I can't have a `PushViewController` statement if I remove that line the Gallery don't load the images, how can I do it use a modal segue? (I don't want use push segue because I'm getting some errors about the navigationcontroller stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code for modal segue. Just change the name of the view controller to the name of the view controller you are using in your project.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFotosAloj"])
   {
    SomeViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
    }
```

P.s, someViewController is the name you have to change.

Comment: IOS6, presentModaViewController is deprecated... change it to presentViewController

Comment: Yes thank you for correction on modal, it should be view not modal. Typo :) try to allocate the data source after instantiating the view controller. Try placing the local galery data source after instantiating so new view can read the data. The code above should present the view but what is in the view is the data source that you need to show. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: if you have added your data source and still not showing then i cant tell you why its not working without looking at the project or try to duplicate the issue which i cant given the small amount of info i have from the project you are working on. the question is still not marked as answered so maybe some one else would contribute.